# How can i make a CSS drop down menu accessible for keyboard navigation?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

I saw already some solutions, but i can't figure out how can i put some of these solutions in my code, or some solutions uses something that i can't use in my project.

Let's go to the question:

I need to make an already existing CSS drop-down menu accessible for keyboard navigation. I got some progress in opening the drop-down menu with [Tab] but i can't navigate into the options inside.

Here is my code:

```css
    .menu .options-menu-dropdown{
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'OpenSans Bold';
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #646464;        
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu .menu-dropdown{
        z-index: -1;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        min-width: 180px;
        text-align: right;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: -6px;
        margin-right: -6px;

        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;    
    }
.menu .options-menu-dropdown:focus .menu-dropdown,
    .menu .options-menu-dropdown:hover .menu-dropdown{
        z-index: 100;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .menu .title-dropdown{
        background-color: #005e8b;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 8px 6px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .menu .menu-dropdown-item{
        display: block;
        background-color: white;        
        padding: 12px 32px 12px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #323232;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; 
        border-top: #b4b4b4 1px solid;
        border-left: #b4b4b4 1px solid;
        border-right: #b4b4b4 1px solid;
    }
    .menu .menu-dropdown-item:last-child{
        border-bottom: #b4b4b4 1px solid;
    }
  .menu .menu-dropdown-item:focus,
    .menu .menu-dropdown-item:hover{
        background-color: #b4b4b4;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="menu" align="center" >
  <div class="options-menu-dropdown" tabindex="0">
    <div>Test Menu</div>
    <div class="menu-dropdown">
      <div class="title-dropdown">Opened Test Menu</div>
      <a href="#" class="menu-dropdown-item" tabindex="1">Menu Item 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu-dropdown-item" tabindex="1">Menu Item 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu-dropdown-item" tabindex="1">Menu Item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

code http://codepen.io/WillCodebit/pen/XpaqqJ

**Note: I'm trying to avoid any javascript solution, because in this project I need to use GWT for any javascript, it is a pattern that I can't violate.**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
This menu should have a similar behavior than the account menu of Google. And the options inside must be accessible by keyboard too.

[image: Menu example]

Comment: You could start by taking a look at the [W3C WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#kbd_general_between) draft. This will make for an interesting read and help guide you to an informed solution.

Comment: Good use is to place your source here. Links to sources can disappear later. So this will be not useful for others with same request.

Comment: You should also avoid using `tabindex` – From my above posted link:

_tabindex="X" where X is an integer in the range 1 <= X <= 32767
Authors are strongly advised NOT to use these values. The element is placed in the tab sequence based on the value of tabindex. Elements with a tabindex value of 0 and elements that are focusable by default will be in the sequence after elements with a tabindex value of 1 or greater._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shannon Youg who tried to help.

I found a solution, but I had to put some Javascript to make it work.

HTML:

```
<div class="my-menu">
  <a id="menuUser" href="javascript:showHideMenu()" class="">
    <div>
      Test
    </div>
  </a>
  <ul id="menuUserDropdown" class="menu-dropdown">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="menu-dropdown-item">
        Option 1
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="menu-dropdown-item">
        Option 2
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="menu-dropdown-item">
        Option 3
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-menu a{
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'OpenSans Bold';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #646464;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.my-menu a div{
  padding: 4px 5px 4px 0;
}
.my-menu a.opened div,
.my-menu a:hover div{
  background-color: #c9252b;
  color: #fff;
}
.my-menu .menu-dropdown.opened{
  display: block;
}
.my-menu div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.my-menu .menu-dropdown{
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 30;
  background-color: #FFF;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
}
.my-menu .menu-dropdown-item{
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 162px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #323232;
}
.my-menu .menu-dropdown-item:focus,
.my-menu .menu-dropdown-item:hover{
  background-color: #b4b4b4;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Javascript, well, I made with GWT, but the logic is simple:

```
/* Just add or remove the class "opened" from "menuUser" and "menuUserDropdown".
    You can put a "blur()" and "mouseLeave()" functions 
    to close the menu when the user moves away the cursor or 
    move the focus out of the menu too. */
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question – but did find my answer scattered over different places on the internet which is why I post my solution here. It is a solution that works without JavaScript. The secret lies in these pseudo classes:

```css
li > a:hover + ul,
li > a:focus + ul,
li:focus-within > ul
```

Full HTML (Header section):

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub page 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub page 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub page 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Full CSS (without actual styling) – the first level elements are displayed next to each other (`display: inline-block;`), the second level elements are hidden and appear as soon as the parent element is active:

```css
header ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

header nav > ul > li > ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

header nav > ul > li > a:hover + ul,
header nav > ul > li > a:focus + ul,
header nav > ul > li:focus-within > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: The solution above worked for me without any java script or GWT code. Just a small change from the above code, instead of using visibility:visible, display:block worked for me.

Comment: @Ramesh The advantage of `visibility` and `opacity` is that you can animate them in CSS :) Otherwise yes, `display: block;` is a simpler way. Thanks for checking this!

Answer (score 0):

[From Heydon Pickering - Practical ARIA examples](http://heydonworks.com/practical_aria_examples/#submenus):

```
<nav role="navigation" aria-label="example with dropdowns">
<ul class="with-dropdowns">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="/about" aria-haspopup="true">About</a>
        <ul aria-hidden="true" aria-label="submenu">
            <li><a href="/about/#who-we-are">Who we are</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/#what-we-do">What we do</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/#why">Why</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I tried to navigate with keyboard in this example and the itens inside the drop-down aren't accessible by keyboard, in my case the itens inside must be accessible by keyboard too.

Comment: Are not accessible or just do not visually display? This code by default is keyboard friendly. The CSS, however, must support it with appropriate `hover` *and* `focus` styles.

Comment: @Will I think you may be confusing _accessibility_ with _functionality_.